# Fire an activity on sms received in android

Tags: android

I am making an application on sms activity, the application is about if a phone lost somewhere in house when its on vibration or silent mode, user can send an sms from any other phone with specific keyword i.e "Lost".  The minute phone receives this sms, an intent fired and it changes to ringer mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can start your Activity on SMS Reciverd as:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";            
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";        
            }
             if(str.contains("YOUR_UNIQUE_KEY"))
              {
                // START YOUR ACTIVITY HERE
                     Intent i = new  Intent(context,SMSActivity.class);
                    i.setLaunchFlags(Intent.NEW_TASK_LAUNCH);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(i);
              }

        }                         
    }
}
```

and for How we Recive SMS in ANDROID see these tutorials:

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

http://www.anddev.org/recognize-react_on_incoming_sms-t295.html

Answer (score 0):

Register BroadcastReceiver Class in your Project listen the incoming sms tutorial and Source code Below link

http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2008/12/android-api-sms-handling/

after Broadcast Receiver Class listen receive sms to Start Activity sample code below:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ReceiveSMS extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    MapMarker obj_gps = new MapMarker();
    Boolean SendSMS;
    String Mobileno;
    String VarMessageBody;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
          Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String str = "";            
            if (bundle != null)
            {
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
                for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                    str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    Mobileno=msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    str += " :";
                    str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    VarMessageBody=msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    str += "\n";
                    Mobileno=msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();

                }
               //---display the new SMS message---
               if (VarMessageBody.startsWith("LOST"))//Check Message Body String Start with START
                    Intent intentHome = new Intent(context, HomeScreen.class);
                    intentHome.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    //intentHome.putExtra("No",Mobileno);
                    //intentHome.putExtra("Msg",VarMessageBody);
                    //intentHome.putExtra("Mob", Mobileno);
                    context.startActivity(intentHome);
              }

              Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }



}
```

This code Receive Send SMS FORMAT "LOST" To Start Activity..!